# generate multi item javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

my api response  is

```
{
  "background_img": "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/workplace.jpg",
  "OB": [
    {
      "shape": "rect",
      "coord": "34,44,270,350",
      "title": "Computer",
    },
    {
      "shape": "poly",
      "coord": "290,172,333,250",
      "title": "Phone"
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to generate these elements depend on api
i try this code but got error:

```
   let xml2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xml2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let response2 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var i=0;
        response2.forEach(element => {
                var area = document.getElementsByTagName('map')[0],
                newArea = document.createElement('area');   //create an area
                newArea.id = `a${i}`;                      //add an id
                newArea.shape =response.OB[i].shape;
                newArea.coords =response.OB[i].cord;
                newArea.alt =response.OB[i].title;
                area.appendChild(newArea);                 //append to the map
                i++;
        });
    }
};
xml2.open("GET", "https://api.site.com", true);
xml2.send();
```

it returns  response2.forEach is not a function

Comment: it's `response2.OB` that is an array, `response2` is an object, so `response2.OB.forEach` instead of `response2.forEach`

Comment: `this.responseText` is an object and objects don't have a `.forEach()` method. What you really want is the `OB` property of the parsed response -> `response2.OB.forEach(...)` (+ adjustments in the callback)

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `i` variable, just use `forEach`'s index like so: `response2.OB.forEach((element, i) =>`, you don't need to increment it at the end